# How to find the the most popular product in graph database?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph database with the following schema made using Neo4j.

```
MATCH (customer{customerid})-[:made]->(purchased{Invoiceno, invoicedate})-[:includes{quantity, invoiceamount}]->(product{stockcode, unitprice})
```

I want the most popular product which is the most customers purchased but I am only able to get the most purchased product by quantity.

```
MATCH (a:customer)-[r1:MADE]->(b:purchase)-[r2:includes]->(c:product)
WITH SUM(r2.quantity) AS totalquantity, c.stockcode AS productcode
RETURN productcode, totalquantity  ORDER BY totalquantity DESC LIMIT 1
```

This was the result.

```
╒═════════════╤═══════════════╕
│"productcode"│"totalquantity"│
╞═════════════╪═══════════════╡
│"84077"      │3552           │
└─────────────┴───────────────┘
```

So, how do I get the most popular product based on most customer buying it ?

Answer (score 1):

If a purchase can contain multiple time the same product, you'll need to traverse the full path from the customer and just return the path counts :

```
MATCH (a:customer)-[r1:MADE]->(b:purchase)-[r2:includes]->(c:product)
RETURN c.id, count(*) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```

If a product can be included in a purchase only once, then you can just return the `degree` of the product for the `includes` relationship :

```
MATCH (c:product)
RETURN c.id, size((c)<-[:includes]-()) AS score
ORDER BY score DESC
LIMIT 1
```